# List of Solution packages are in the solution store

Tags: 2007, administration, powershell, central-administration

How to find a list of Solution packages are in the solution store in sharePoint 2007 using Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
$farm
```

to the the `SPFarm` object and you will have access to the `Solutions` collection.

Source: [Getting an SPFarm object using PowerShell](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2009/04/getting-spfarm-object-using-powershell.html)